# Countour plot - in Matplotlib

Tags: python, contour

I have a bunch of XY data and a binary outcome. So something that looks like this:

```
   X     Y    Z
-1.2   2.5    1   
 1.1   3.2    0
 0.7   1.7    1
-1.2   4.1    1
...
...

[10000 rows]
```

This is data for baseball pitches. It gives the X,Y coords and whether it is a strike. A heatmap of the data looks like this:

[image]

And I want to produce a contour plot that in essence shows a "50% zone". Something that looks like this:

[image]

I have used this code essentially creating a numpy array from a data frame, using meshgrid, griddata and plt.contour:

```
df2_array = df2[['plate_x', 'plate_z', 'strike']].to_numpy()

X,Y = np.meshgrid(df2_array[:,0], df2_array[:,1])

Z = griddata((df2_array[:,0], df2_array[:,1]), df2_array[:,2], (X, Y), method='linear')

levels = 2
plt.contour(X, Y, Z, levels, alpha = 0.5)
```

And I get this output:

[image]

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail what you expect the "50% zone" to look like? Could be a circle with 50% of strikes, could be a rectangle, could be square. If you have no further constraints on the shape of the area, there is no distinct solution.

Comment: If you look at the first hexbin plot - you can see that the 50% zone is the turquoise colour -- so it is a ring - similar to what I expecting to see in the second image.

Another way to ask the question is take the hexbin plot (top imagine) and plot a 50% ring instead of the colours

Comment: I don't understand why there would be no solution. My original idea was to hexbin and use that to find the 50% point ...

Comment: OK, got you. But I still cannot reproduce your issues. Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Here is a colab notebook that you should be able to access

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ipTzpW1hGAWlsFE8Ax-kD5ly7sMGxqNI?usp=sharing